# Cannot run Python Docker containers on Apple M1 / macOS Monterrey 12.4

Tags: python, docker, flask, apple-m1

For a while now I am unable to run Python Flask within a Docker container on a M1 Macbook. I am on macOS Monterrey 12.4, but the problem was already occuring on 12.3. My Flask app is super basic:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Hello, World!</p>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(port='5000')
```

So is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm64v8/python:latest

RUN mkdir /templates

COPY templates/* ./templates

COPY requirements.txt app.py ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run"]
```

I run the following Docker commands in my repo:

```
docker build -t quick-test .

docker run -d -p 5000:5000 quick-test
```

When I visit my localhost:5000, I get a ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE in my browser. This happens time and time again, also in other Flask apps. I reviewed my ports and this is the only thing running at 5000.

Also tried to install the Intel Docker Desktop w/ Rosetta 2, but to no avail. Other things I tried is to change the Docker image to ARM64 architecture (didn't change anything), and running it on a different M1 Mac than mine (which produced the same result).

When I tested it on another M1 Mac, I got the idea this is a M1 issue with Docker. But could it be? Any directions?

Comment: This version of Macbook uses the port 5000. Did you try to run your Docker container on a different port? `docker run -d -p 5001:5000 quick-test`?

Comment: Yes, I did. First on 8080, then on 5001 and some random ports above 5000. Didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 5000 on mac can be used by control center and it can cause problems local development. I changed the configured port and exposed the same port and docker and it works without any issues

Dockerfile

```
FROM arm64v8/python:latest

COPY requirements.txt app.py ./

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8050

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host" ,"0.0.0.0", "--port", "8050"]
```

Now run build the image and run

```
docker build -t quick-test .

docker run -d -p 8050:8050 quick-test
```

You can now see the app running on localhost:8050

Comment: This did the trick. I didn't know about Control Center occupying port 5000. Thanks.